# sql order by specific value in column and than order alphabetical the rest of the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Have have a simple `select * from myTable` query, and a column called `Fruits`

`Fruits` has the following data:

```
Apple
Pear
Peach
Plum
Grape
```

I always want Grape first and then the rest of them in order so the result would be

```
Grape
Apple
Peach
Pear
Plum
```

As always thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE([Fruits] VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES('Apple')
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES('Pear')
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES('Peach')
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES('Plum')
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES('Grape')

SELECT * 
FROM @myTable
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN([Fruits] = 'Grape') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    [Fruits]
```

In the `ORDER BY`, you are assigning a value when the `[Fruits]` field is `Grape` so you can sort on that first, and then you do a secondary sort on the `[Fruits]` field.

Comment: This solution has the advantage of not requiring a schema change, but takes a larger performance hit since you have to do more work to sort them.

Comment: @cdeszaq You are correct. I would probably change the schema if I had to run this query frequently and I knew that this table had the potential to have a large number of records. The performance hit is probably negligible on a table with a smaller number of rows.

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from myTable
order by
     case when Fruits = 'Grape' then 0 else 1 end,
     Fruits
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an ordinal column to your Fruits table and give Grapes the lowest ordinal (1) and the rest of the fruit a different value (2 would work well).

You can then order by the ordinal, and then the fruit name. That will put the Grapes at the top, and then the rest below in Alpha order.